# Best way to update object based on given ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm working on my first React personal mini project. Please go easy on me..

In the past hour, i've been trying to source for the best way to update an item in an array based on a given ID. I found that this way seems to be the one people are using (using `findIndex`). I might not have searched deep enough was wondering if anyone could point out or improve on it?

I've seen other methods too but i'm not too sure if it's the **best way**, though many ways.

Here i've my state

```
state = {
    cards: [],
    updateId: ''
};
```

This is how i updated it in a method handler

```
submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.formAddState) {
      const editCard = {
        reason: this.state.reason,
        description: this.state.description
      };
      let newCards = [...this.state.cards];
      let indexUpdate = newCards.findIndex(
        card => card.id === this.state.updateId
      );
      newCards[indexUpdate].reason = editCard.reason;
      newCards[indexUpdate].description = editCard.description;
      this.setState({
        cards: newCards
      });
      return;
    }
};
```

Could be a duplicate.. Ultimately, i'd like to learn!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are struggling there too much. If you know the `id` of the card, then you can map the cards and if there is not a match you can return the card itself, else you can update it with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
submit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { cards, updateId, reason, description, formAddState } = this.state;

  if (!formAddState) {
    let newCards = cards.map(card => {
      if (card.id !== updateId) return card;
      return { ...card, reason, description };
    });
    this.setState({
      cards: newCards
    });
  }
};
```

As you can see there isn't any **best way** to do that. You should write your code according to your needs. You can use different methods to update your state. Just, **do not mutate your state directly and use the right tools to update your state**. You should treat your state as immutable. This is why I'm returning a new array in my example and return the updated card by spread syntax.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cards: [
      { id: 1, reason: "foo", description: "foo desc" },
      { id: 2, reason: "bar", description: "bar desc" },
      { id: 3, reason: "baz", description: "baz desc" }
    ],
    updateId: 1,
    reason: "changed reason",
    description: "changed description",
    formAddState: false
  };

  submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { cards, updateId, reason, description, formAddState } = this.state;

    if (!formAddState) {
      let newCards = cards.map(card => {
        if (card.id !== updateId) return card;
        return { ...card, reason, description };
      });
      this.setState({
        cards: newCards
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.submit}>Change</button>
        {this.state.cards.map(card => (
          <div>
            <p>{card.id}</p>
            <p>{card.reason}</p>
            <p>{card.description}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: I like this technique more than splicing the array. (upvoted both anyway)

Comment: Yeah, I like it more too :) Though, some can argue mapping all the array like that for performance issues maybe. Since `findIndex` returns the id immediately when it matches.

Comment: But he is spreading the array and splicing afterward, so I guess that any perf gain from `find` is lost anyway. And performance shouldn't be an issue unless we're dealing with huge arrays in a time critical application, which shouldn't rely on JS in the end :P

Comment: I agree :) "...premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." _Donald Knuth_

Comment: thank you to all for your help! i did try using the array.map functionality too, it's cleaner and more understandable imo. but just can't wrap my head around with which to be the better way. like you said devserkan there's no best way, just what we need. In terms of what you said @Emile Bergeron, what else can we look for other than JS? Could you please enlighten me, i'd like to learn! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that your state is the following array:

```
const [state, setState] = useState([{id: 1, value: 'foo'},{id:2, value:'it\'s never lupus'}])
```

And you want to update only a given id and replace it's value:

```
const updater = (id, value) =>{
    const item = state.find(x => x.id === id)
    const updatedItem = {...item, value}
    const newState = [...state]
    newState.splice(state.indexOf(item),1, updatedItem)
    setState(newState)
}
```